# Issue in drag and drop II

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I need clarifcation on the drag and drop (quiz type module). Already asked same question, but this time with improvised version.

I'm using jqueryUI for creating quiz type questions. When I drag and drop correct answer(third one) to droppable area  and click check,it should turn green and show a tick symbol. Rest of options, it should turn red and show wrong symbol. Now it is working partially. 
Can anyone please help me on this?

my code- https://codepen.io/vimalraj86/pen/zYGoPag

**My logic:**

**JQUERY UI:**
if { 
drag and drop c into droppable area. 
add class on droppable area ".correct"
else{
add class on droppable area as ".wrong"
}
}

**JQUERY:**
if #droppable hasClass() correct, then show #tick.
else show #wrong.

```
$(function() {

  $("div[id^='draggable']").draggable();
  $("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      if (ui.draggable.text().trim() == "C") {
        $(this).addClass("ui-state-green")

      } else {
        $(this).addClass("ui-state-red")
      }
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("check").click(function(){
    $(this).show();
  });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. First, your `$("check")` is using incorrect Syntax. The Selector for an ID is `$("#check")`. Second, I do not see a tick or check mark in your example. So that's very unclear.

Comment: @Twisty Now I have updated the link... please check.. if my option is correct, class correct must be added o droppable area..and tick mark should be shown..else wrong mark must be shown...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  function checkAnswer(e) {
    var a = $(".answered .ui-widget-content");
    if (a.length == 1 && a.text().trim() == "C") {
      $(".answered").removeClass("ui-state-red").addClass("ui-state-green");
    } else {
      $(".answered").removeClass("ui-state-green").addClass("ui-state-red");
    }
  }

  function resetQuestion() {
    $(".ui-widget-header").removeClass("answered ui-state-red ui-state-green");
    $(".ui-widget-header .ui-widget-content").each(function(i, el) {
      var i = parseInt($(el).attr("id").slice(-1));
      var me = $(el).detach();
      console.log(i, me);
      if (i == 0) {
        me.prependTo($(".answers"));
      } else {
        me.insertAfter($(".answers").children().eq((i - 1)));
      }
    });
  }

  $("[id^='draggable']").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.draggable.detach().css({
        left: "",
        top: ""
      }).appendTo($(this));
      $(this).addClass("answered");
      $(".buttons").show();
    }
  });

  $("#check").click(checkAnswer);
  $("#reset").click(resetQuestion);
});
```

```css
#draggable-0,
#draggable-1,
#draggable-2,
#draggable-3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
}

hr {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}

#droppable {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
}

#droppable.ui-state-green {
  background: green;
}

#droppable.ui-state-red {
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header"></div>
  <hr/>
  <div class="answers">
    <div id="draggable-0" class="ui-widget-content">
      <p>A</p>
    </div>
    <div id="draggable-1" class="ui-widget-content">
      <p>B</p>
    </div>
    <div id="draggable-2" class="ui-widget-content">
      <p>C</p>
    </div>
    <div id="draggable-3" class="ui-widget-content">
      <p>D</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons" style="display: none;">
    <button id="reset" href="">reset</button>
    <button id="check" href="">check</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the logic behind this code:

- User Drags a tile from Answers into field
- Reset & Check buttons appear
- User can click Reset or Click

  - Reset will clear any colors and move tiles back in order
  - Check will indicate if the tile in the field is correct or not

It is best to try and move repeatable script into Functions so they can be used frequently.

For Droppable, in `drop`, you will need to perform a few more steps to ensure that the draggable is now a child of the droppable.